# "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version" after upgrade

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6.3

I had Xcode 6.3 beta and iOS 8.3 beta, I updated to the public final versions and now I cannot run anything, getting this error:

> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS
>   version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to
>   run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I have tried everything other posts have said with no luck (my iPhone is "used for development", Base SDK = latest iOS (iOS 8.3), Xcode 6.3 (6D570), iOS 8.3 (12F70), Deployment target=8.0, deleted derived data, restarted Xcode, opened up iTunes)

Anyone out there having the same problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you try this one?

For **XCode 6.3**, go to Menu: **Product > Destination >** and select **your Device name**. Though it says your device is ineligible it will allow you to select the device. That's it!!

If your device version is >= target version, the build will work.

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't make any sense, but it worked. It seems bugs in Xcode 6 are still far from solved.

Comment: Happy that it helped you. Yes, it is a bug in XCode 6.3.

Comment: worked like a charm. No clue why it was reading as inelligible, but thankyou!

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself:

Is your iPhone updated to 8.3 release (not beta)?

Is your project's Base SDK lower than your device?

It only happens if your Base SDK is less than your device version or if your deployment target is higher than your device version.

Your app should work if Base SDK >= device >= deployment target.

Comment: I have the same problem.  In General -> Deployment Target = 8.2.  There is no way to change to 8.3.  How can I make iPhone 8.2 or Deployment Target 8.3?

Comment: @karlml such as? Update frameworks and try again, there shouldn't be too many errors in obj-c. You can always convert swift to 1.2 automatically.

Comment: Yes thanks, also one on "Immutable value of type ... only has mutating members named 'append'. I was thinking of posting a question when U.S. gets online, sometimes when I post questions GMT they are not answered.

Comment: @karlml there's always people living at the other end of the time zones :-) were you able to figure out how to fix the immutable value of type problem?

Comment: Nope, I posted the question now:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603392/sdk-8-3-immutable-value-only-has-mutating-members-named-append

Comment: Yes, base SDK = latest iOS (iOS 8.3), Xcode 6.3 (6D570), iOS 8.3 (12F70), Deployment target=8.0. I cannot figure out what Xcode is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, restarting everything fixed nothing.

On the general tab of the project, select the app target you want to build. Change your Deployment Target to the most recent one (8.3). You should now be able to build for the device. Select your old deployment target and it will still build for the device.