# SDK 8.3 Immutable value ... only has mutating members named 'append'

Tags: ios

I updated to Xcode SDK 8.3 and Swift 1.2: I auto converted using the new menu item: Edit -> Convert -> "To latest Swift Syntax".  It solved all the as? errors but I was left with this one:

> Immutable value of type '[DetailView]' only has mutating members named 'append'

**class DetailView**

```
class DetailView {
    var title: String
    var icon: UIImage
    var fontColor: UIColor
    var highlightOpaqueColor: UIColor

    init(title: String, icon:UIImage, fontColor: UIColor, highlightOpaqueColor: UIColor){
        self.title = title
        self.icon = icon
        self.fontColor = fontColor
        self.highlightOpaqueColor = highlightOpaqueColor


}
```

**class DetailViewSteps:DetailView**

```
class DetailViewSteps:DetailView {

    override init(
        title: String,
        icon: UIImage,
        fontColor: UIColor,
        highlightOpaqueColor:UIColor){

            super.init(
                title: title,
                icon: icon,
                fontColor:fontColor,
                highlightOpaqueColor:highlightOpaqueColor,

    }
```

**class DetailViewInstanceList**

```
class DetailViewInstanceList {


    let detailView:[DetailView] = []

class var sharedInstance: DetailViewInstanceList {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = DetailViewInstanceList()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}


    let assets = Assets()

    init(){
        println("setting up DetailViewInstanceList")


    var steps = DetailViewSteps(
        title: "Steps",
        icon: UIImage(named: assets.stepsIconFileName)!,
        fontColor: assets.stepsFontColor,
        highlightOpaqueColor: assets.stepsOpaqueColor,


    //Add it to the array
        detailView.append(steps) <-- error!
```

The error happens on the last line.  I thought initialising the class with var steps = DetailViewSteps(... would solve the immutable, but no.  Any help would be very much appreciated ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var detailView:[DetailView] = []`

let is immutable, var is mutable.

Comment: ahh, so sorry, totally blind.  But why did this error show up after the update to swift 1.2? Any idea?